# How to add class name when serialize to json by net.sf.json

Tags: java, json-lib

I am planning to provide a interface to iOS Apps, the developer asked to add an additional field call `class` contains the name of the pojo I used on server so he can convert to his class on client easily. The problem is I have to do this when the json lib is processing the values.I think the `registerJsonValueProcessor` can do the trick. I got then class name by `obj.getClass().getName()` but I still have no idea how to attach it to json-lib.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jackson for serialization/deserialization of json than please apply the annotation JsonTypeInfo on your class. It could help you
*@JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.CLASS, include=As.PROPERTY, property="class")*